# Is it possible to use typescript mapped types to make a type of non-function properties of an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, mapped-types

so I was looking at Typescript's mapped types. Would it be possible to create an interface that wraps another type that removes functions from the original type? For example:

```js
interface Person{
name: string,
age: number,
speak(): void,
}

type Data<T> = ?

const dataPerson: Data<Person> ={
name: "John",
age: 20
//Speak removed because it is a function
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is from the typescript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) and works:

```js
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type Data<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
  { [K in T]: T[K] extends Function ? undefined : T[K] }
```

You can use a mapped conditional type for that.

Comment: That didn't quite work for me; consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130199/238884);

Comment: Using undefined instead of never will mean that the property still needs to be part of the object, but that it needs to be the value undefined