# Reconstruct generic class with parameters in the constructor

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a class method that will reconstruct the class with given data.

For example,

```
class A {
   constructor (one, two) {...}

  public static from(data: A): A {
    return Object.assign(new A(), data);
  }
}
```

And then do something like:

```
let someObj = A.from({one: 'hello', two: 'world'}
```

This works fine. But now I want to make this method generic, to call it with any class.

I have tried

```
export function from<T>(type: { new (): T }, input: T): T {
  return Object.assign(new type(), input);
}
```

But the issue is that this wont work if the class needs arguments in the constructor.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.create` to create an object with a specified prototype, without calling the constructor. By setting the object's prototype to `type.prototype`, it will be an instance of the class `type`, so it will have the methods defined by that class, just as it would by calling `new type()`.

```js
function from<T>(type: { new(...args: any[]): T }, input: T): T {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(type.prototype), input);
}
```

It must be said that this is a clear violation of encapsulation, so you have to promise that you will only use it to create objects with valid internal states. Since the constructor is not called, there is no opportunity for the object to validate its own state.

Example:

```js
class A {
    constructor(public x: number) { }
    getX() { return this.x; }
}

var a = new A(1);
var b = from(A, a);
var c = from(A, { x: 4 }); // type error here, unfortunately.

console.log(b.getX()); // logs 1
console.log(c.getX()); // logs 4
```

The type annotation `input: T` unfortunately causes the compiler to complain that `{ x: 4 }` doesn't have the `getX` property that an instance of `A` ought to. We can fix this by constructing [a mapped type which excludes the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130347/12299000):

```js
type FieldsOf<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T]>;

function from<T>(type: { new(...args: any[]): T }, input: FieldsOf<T>): T {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(type.prototype), input);
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwM4HkBmAeAKgPigF4oAFOAYwGs8AaKAbygG0BpKOAOyiohAHtMUXAF0AXMLYioEAB7AInNLACunCsDj9uAfiicIANwgAnKBPYBfZrwFDR+ANwAoZ5jUat3TCf4BbPHwAClBICSYDAHcggDo4gEMTAHNUCXjOEGYRAEoJXChLei4wFWAJeCQ0LEDc4UZnKEaoEwhgFRNudAAjACsIDRj41FQ4JM4g7r6Bihb4hRDwCBiwX2B+UIhsos4S4GyXS1cKRCHUKABBeqaoCm1UYBMVDX4TIJKuxEooWQlOFT8uqZsowCg0mklWgANILApgtNodKDAAAWcFQMVkjlBh2chkSUHixH0EEiFyCAEZ9rj8V0iT5-EFzvR4lS8WYKHTfH5GfQmD8oAAWApU5y3TiofiIJaIfhJIJdGIQ4DQ7JUsUSqUxGVyiiKqEwqlAA)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with going
`export function from<T>(type: { new (): T }, input: T): T {
  return new type(input);
}`

Comment: That has the same problem as `new type()` has; it only works if the class has a constructor with that specific signature. It has the further problem of not working if the class does have a constructor with that signature, but which doesn't do what you want with the `input` object.

Comment: a question came to mind, how would we change this to work also with classes that are inheriting other classes? because now `object.assign` will create a copy of the class with only its own properties. But what about properties from the super class?

Comment: It works absolutely fine with inheritance, because the properties are looked up on the prototype chain. Try e.g. `class B extends A { getXSquared() { return this.x * this.x; } }` then `var c = from(B, { x: 4 }); console.log(c.getXSquared());`.